# Is it okay to leave Schengen on the day my visa expires?

Tags: schengen-visas, visa-expiration

I am travelling with multiple-entry Schengen visa to Rome. My departure date is the same day as my visa expiration date. Is it legal?

Comment: When you acquired that visa, what (if anything) did you tell the consular officials you were planning to do? Is your actual departure date radically different from those plans?

Comment: It's legal but not wise. If your departure is delayed for any reason you will have breached the terms of your visa. Plan to leave a day or two earlier.

Comment: It is legal as long as you don't breach the "number of days" mentioned in your visa.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fulfill two criteria to stay in the Schengen Area:

1. Have a valid visa
2. Have obeyed the [90/180 rule](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13183/how-does-the-schengen-90-180-rule-work)

On the day you're planning your departure you have a valid visa, so the first criteria is fulfilled. You haven't said anything that allows us to say whether you will have obeyed the 90/180 rule.

But consider that your plane is cancelled or delayed for another reason, then you will suddenly not have a valid visa anymore, and thus have broken the rules. So what you're thinking of doing *might* (as said above, you have only given information that allows us to look at one of two requirements) be valid, but it isn't wise.

Comment: If you are at the airport on the last day of the visa and the plane doesn't fly, there are procedures to get an 'emergency' extension. But it is easier to have a day (of validity *and* duration) to spare.